# presenting and pushing viewcontrollers in swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift3

I am working in storyboard and also programmatically do some things. First, I have created a viewController `controller` which is login page (first view) programmatically. But in storyboard I have a `NavigationController` whose root is `ViewController`. Everything (methods `forgotPassword` and `loginDidFinish`) worked fine, except that `ViewController` was viewed before `controller` immediately after launching the app.

So I have changed the root of `NavigationController` to `controller`, and after that my functions does not work. I've tried several things like deleting navcontrol in storyboard, etc. You can see my project here: https://github.com/ardulat/SPE

Comment: sorry, forgot to update a repo from a link

Comment: Try to remove `is initial view controller` option or just select an arrow on the left and delete it from your navigation controller is storyboard. And if you create loginVC programmatically then your should have some code probably in `appDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function`.

Comment: @mikle94 did not worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I will provide you a basic example of a Login scenario, hope it can help you with your issue, what I would do first is set right the navigation between ViewControllers like this:

[image]

---

I have two view controllers in my project (**LoginViewController.swift** and **MainViewController.swift**):

[image]

---

So in my storyboard I create two ViewControllers, the first one embedded with NavigationController then I set a segue from my first ViewController to my second ViewController:

[image]

---

Then I give a name to the segue I created like so:

[image]

---

And in order to navigate from **Login** to **Main** ViewController, I call the **performSegue** method inside the **loginButtonTapped** action that is triggered when the login **button** is touched.

LoginViewController.swift:

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }

  @IBAction func loginButtonTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    // TODO: validate your login form

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "LoginToMain", sender: nil)
  }


}
```

Comment: this is pretty obvious, and not the thing i can not solve.